# AWS RDS PostgreSQL snapshot gray out migration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We are planning to migrate a RDS PostgreSQL database to aurora. First I made a snapshot, but the migration option is grayed out. Our PostgreSQL version is 11.13. From the AWS documentation it mentioned that: **'starting with the release of PostgreSQL versions 13.3, 12.8, 11.13, 10.18, and for all other later versions, Aurora version numbers aren't used.**', I do not understand what does this means. Is this a version problem? Please advise what should I do. Thanks

[image]

Comment: To which version, and why? Could you please explain this a little bit?

Comment: Is Aurora available in your region? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#aurora

Comment: Yes，Our rds in region us-east-1

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot please?